# Can we customize the font of the CSV file created by CHCSV Parser?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, csv, export-to-csv

I am using CHCSV Parser to write my data to CSV file in my iOS applocation. I successfully done that task.

Know I want to customize the font and color of the column header and the data fields and want to give column width for each column field.

Can I customize the CSV file using CHCSV Parser or any other way to do it.

Comment: Csv is an exchange format. It does not know anything about styling.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: You don't have to give -1 to it because I am only asking can i do it. If you are confirm that we can't do it then you can answer me like "We can't do it".

Comment: @Yash i dont think you can actually see who gave you -1 assuming that the person who commented gave you -1 is wrong

Comment: I voted -1. Everyone working with csv should instinctively know that it is not about prettyprinting but an exchange format for getting data from a to b. you simply did not do your homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot format csv file. csv is data exchange format. I suppose you need to show it in user interface then its better you design some UI instead of showing raw csv data.